How to enter Scarlet Halls / Scarlet Monastery / Scholomance in Pandaria Remix?
So I know that I can queue for those on the LFG tool, but how can I physically enter the instance in case I want to solo it? I understand I cannot get to the Easter Kingdom so is there some portal or NPC that can teleport me there?
Edit: Please note this question is about WoW Remix Mists of Pandaria, this is a seasonal mode in which you can only play in Pandaria, you cannot leave and go to any of the other continents. For example, the portal in the Shrine of the Seven Stars that will teleport you to Stormwind does not exist in this version:


Why can't you enter the eastern kingdoms?

@A.bakker being in the new seasonal mode Pandaria Remix you cannot leave Pandaria by normal means such as hearthstone, mage teleport, portals in the shrines, etc.

I just happened to randomly find this out, Dawnbringer Riyang in the Seat of Knowledge in the Veil of Eternal Blossoms.  They'll teleport you to those dungeons - inside the portal doesn't work, need to talk to a Panda to leave.

Dawnbringer Riyang (https://www.wowhead.com/npc=223738/dawnbringer-riyang) can be found at /way #390 83.0 30.6
